# Error http 422 and XMLHttpRequest in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to connect to a web service. When I use postman, request send and response receive successfully. But in the flutter app, I get `error 422` in the android emulator. And with the same code in flutter web, I get `XMLHttpRequest error`.

My postman:

[image: scrennshot]

This is my data that send to the server:

```
var data = {
  "username": usernameController.text,
  "password": passwordController.text,
  "email": emailController.text
};
```

And send a request with dio:

```
Response response = await client
        .post(theUrl,
            options: Options(headers: {
              HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
              HttpHeaders.acceptHeader:"*/*"
            }),
            data: jsonEncode(data))
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));
```

I get errors on this method:

```
on DioError catch (error) {
    var statusCode = error.response?.statusCode;
    print("+++++++++++++++" + statusCode.toString());
    print("+++++++++++++++" + error.message);
}
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Maybe... https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422

Comment: Where do you encode the `data` map into JSON?

Comment: @RichardHeap Thank you, I edit my code and add jsonEncode to dio. but the error still is 422 in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I Added this code to options in dio and Error 422 in mobile is fixed:

```
Options(
  validateStatus: (status) {
    return status! < 500;
   },
   followRedirects: false,
   ...)
```

But I still get error `XMLHttpRequest` in flutter web.

Comment: The web problem will be a CORS issue.

Comment: @RichardHeap The server programmer says that CORS is enable on server

Comment: Open the Developer Tools tab in chrome - open the Network tab - then perform the request.